# Showing a topology is coarser than another using bases

Tags: general-topology

To show that a topology is coarser than another, does it suffice to show that its basis is a subset of the basis for the other topology? This of course fits with my intuition but I'm not seeing this as a definition or theorem anywhere. Is it just because it is obvious or have I gone wrong somewhere here?

Comment: If ‘$\tau$ is coarser than $\tau'$’ is understood to mean that $\tau\subseteq\tau'$, this is true, for the reason that **Eric Wofsey** gives in his answer. This usage of *coarser* is sloppy but very common, possibly even customary. If, however, it means that $\tau\subsetneqq\tau'$, then you have to do a bit more.

Comment: Yes I see that thank you; my class distinguishes this by using the terms "strictly finer" and "strictly coarser"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this suffices.  If $B$ and $C$ are bases for topologies on a set $X$ and $B\subseteq C$, then any union of elements of $B$ is also a union of elements of $C$ (since every element of $B$ is an element of $C$), and so the topology generated by $B$ is contained in the topology generated by $C$.